# How do I determine date in history when the moons sidereal month was 27.416 days long?

Tags: the-moon

I understand that the moon's orbit is gradually increasing because it's moving away from Earth at a rate of about 3.8 cm per year.  I also understand that there isn't enough long term data to assume that the moon has been moving away from Earth at that rate constantly.  I am trying to determine a date in history (assuming that the moon has been moving away from Earth at 3.8 cm per year) when the sidereal month was 27.416 days long.  How on Earth would I calculate something like that ? Anyone out there willing to lend me a hand ?  Please.

Kind Regards
Edwin

Comment: The change of the Moon's orbit is caused by tidal fricition. For a short period of time you may assume a constant rate. But for very long period when the continents are moving you can not assume a constant tidal friction. Tides a very complex, they are caused by the Moon and the Sun but also the shape of the coast lines.

Comment: This is an astronomy question, not really a space exploration question.

Comment: Thank you Uwe.  I guess my question should be then, is it possible to determine the rate of change in the moons mean sidereal month over a period of say 10000 years ???

Answer (score 2):

A recession of 3.8cm increases its current distance by about one part in $10^{10}$. By Kepler's third law, the square of the period is in proportion to the cube of the distance, which suggests a change in period of roughly 1.5 parts in $10^{10}$ per year -- roughly 400 microseconds.

Changes in the rate relate to changes in tidal flows in the oceans, which are likely to come from two sources (before humans got involved, anyway) continental drift on a timescale of millions of years or the cycle of ice ages on a timescale of tens of thousands. If we can safely ignore ice ages,  then the change would be about 7 minutes per million years.

Now, you want to know when the *sidereal* month was 27.416 days. However, it's only 27.321 days now, and increasing, so this date is in the future. In fact, assuming we can ignore ice ages, it is about 20 million years from now.  The *synodic* month (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month)) is about 29.5 days now, so *that* was 27.416 days a long time ago. In fact long enough for continental drift to be definitely non-ignorable.

Comment: It seems that the term "[sidereal month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month#Sidereal_month)" refers to the period of the Moon's orbit with respect to the stars; 27.321661 days, so the difference is only 0.094 days, not 2 days, if I understand correctly. That may affect your calculation and your conclusions.

Comment: Not only continental drift would be non ignorable, but also a change of the submarine ground by vulcanic activities, sedimentation and movement of the shelf by currents. Also melting of the ice at the north and south pole.